# Como saber percentual da animação no CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, jquery-animate

Procurei e não encontrei uma função ou propriedade do atributo animate (CSS), para acompanhar e controlar o percentual de uma animação CSS. Ou seja, eu quero, dinamicamente, saber em quantos porcento está a execução da animação e intervir, com uma função, em determinados pontos da execução. PS: existem os atributos animationstart, animationend e animationiteration. Mas para percentual? Alguma técnica que faça o equivalente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando JavaScript (jQuery) é possível calcular a porcentagem da animação, usando os eventos `animationstart` (quando inicia) e `animationend` (quando termina), e em qualquer parte da animação usar um `if` para executar uma ação em determinada porcentagem, que vai de 0 a 100%.

A lógica é usar `setInterval()` no intervalo onde você divide o tempo da animação por 100, ou seja, o `setInterval()` deverá rodar 100 vezes; e a cada volta do `setInterval()` uma variável irá ser incrementada com +1. Essa variável que determinada em que posição percentual a animação está ocorrendo.

Só tem um detalhe: o valor do tempo da animação deve ser em segundos, por exemplo:

```
animation: anima 3s linear forwards;
                 ↑
             3 segundos
```

Poderia ser também em milissegundos, mas aí teria que fazer uma checagem no código, aumentando mais umas linhas. Mas eu fiz para pegar apenas em segundos, que achei mais prático.

**Veja um exemplo:**

CSS:

```
div{
   position: relative;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background: red;
}

@keyframes anima {
  from {left: 0;}
  to {left: 200px;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<button>Iniciar animação</button>
<div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $("button").on("click", function(){
      var tempo; // variável a ser usada no setInterval

      $("div").css("animation", "anima 3s linear forwards");

      $("div").on("animationstart animationend", function(e){

         var $this = $(this); // elemento animado
         var duracao = parseFloat($this.css("animation-duration")); // pega a duração da animação
         var steps = (duracao*1000)/100; // determina o tempo do setInterval
         var perc = 0; // variável do percentual

         if(e.type == "animationstart"){
            tempo = setInterval(function(){
               perc++;
               var pos = parseFloat($this.css("left"));
               $this.html(perc+"%");

               // faz algo quando atingir os 50%
               if(perc == 50){
                  console.log("faz alguma coisa em 50%");
               }

            }, steps);
         }else if(e.type == "animationend"){
            clearInterval(tempo); // para o temporizador
            $this.html("100%");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Teste no **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d4y0ph3k/)** porque aqui não funciona.

Comment: Sam, vlw pela dica, funciona! PS: só uma coisinha: a variável "pos" foi inicializada e não utilizada, correto? Ou seja, eu posso interferir nesta animação, tanto pelo acompanhamento do percentual executado (variável perc), quanto pela posição relativa do elemento animado (variável pos) é isso? O que me faz pensar que também poderia interferir por outras variáveis adquiridas e acompanhadas na análise feita com o setInterval(), ok?

Answer (score -1):

Então, você pode fazer sua animação do início.

Saca só:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}
```

esse é um exemplo de animação css para "balanço". Perceba que, a cada porcentagem, é possível interferir colocando outra ação.

É chato de fazer, mas assim dá certo.

Comment: E como que com `animationstart, animationend, animationiteration` ele detecta onde a animação está e faz a função JS? Pelo que entendi esse é o problema da pergunta, e não dividir a animação em % no CSS...